# Is chaining of criteria query a good practice?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, java-ee-6

I am a chaining criteria query for my Java EE based project but I'm not really sure whether it is a good practice or not.

There are many advantages like it decreases the code and more importantly initial queries can be reused. But I don't know what its disadvantages can be.

Please see it once and suggest me whether I am on the right track. It is working excellent in my project.

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;
    protected CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery;
    protected CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
    protected Root<T> from;
    protected List<Predicate> predicates;

    @PostConstruct
protected void _startQuery() {
    this.criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    this.criteriaQuery = this.criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
    from = this.criteriaQuery.from(entityClass);
    predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
}
```

> ..........................
>       ..........................

```
}


public abstract class AbstractUserLoggableFacade<T extends AbstractUserLoggable> extends AbstractFacade<T> {

   .................
}


public abstract class OrganizationTrackableFacade<T extends OrganizationalTrackable> extends AbstractUserLoggableFacade<T> {


........................
}
```

And finally the implementation class.

```
 @Stateless
    public class DayStartFacade extends OrganizationTrackableFacade<DayStart> {

       @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
        private DayStartFacade filterByEnded(Boolean b) {
            this.predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(DayStart_.isEnded), b));
            return this;
        }

         @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
        private DayStartFacade filterByOrganization(Organization o) {
            this.predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(OrganizationalTrackable_.organizationId), o));
            return this;
        }
```

And here's my chained method. Is it a good practice to chain in this way?

```
 public DayStart getCurrentDayStart() {
        DayStart d = null;
        try {
            d = ((DayStartFacade) this.startQuery()).filterByEnded(Boolean.FALSE).filterByOrganization(userBean.getCurrentOrganization()).getSingleResult();
        } catch (javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException e) {
            System.out.println("No unique restult exception at getCurrentDayStart");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException nre) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate and GlassFish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't ok, the API wouldn't allow it. Since the `javax.persistence.criteria` package is full of this pattern, it is likely intended.

Comment: Actually ,I was doubting for its efficiency and reliability.Thanks for the suggestion.Now ,I also have similar understanding.